# Grouped Boxplots

Tags: r, boxplot

I have data frame and I want to plot grouped boxplots. Here is part of the data.

```
a <- c(0, 100, 250, 500, 750, 0, 100, 250, 500, 750, 0, 100, 250, 500, 750)
b <- c(2.646, 3.756, 26.270, 30.997, 39.294,  2.646, 3.756, 26.270, 30.997, 39.294, 16.363, 25.950, 38.913,45.000, 47.698)
c <- c(0.0, 0.5, 0.1, 5.8, 21.9, 0.0, 0.5, 0.1, 5.8, 21.9, 9.7. 12.5, 25.1, 29.3, 31.9)
d <- c(14.7, 15.0, 13.8, 18.4, 28.2, 14.7, 15.0, 13.8, 18.4, 28.2, 23.6, 24.0, 25.7, 29.0, 33.1)
```

I merged the vectors to get a data frame as follows.

```
data <- cbind(a, b, c, d)
```

Then I tried to get boxplot for the three values of b, c and d as a funtion of a as follows.

```
boxplot(b~a, c~a, d~a, data = data)
```

but I couldn't get the desired grouped boxplot which is three boxplots for each value of "a". But I can get a boxplot for each value of "a"  if I do:

```
boxplot(b~a, data = data)
```

What is wrong with my grouped boxplot?

Comment: To begin with: a, b, c, d have different lengths.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the solution by Thierry, but using `boxplot(long$value ~ long$a + long$variable)` instead of ggplot, once you have converted to long with melt() and factorized a. It is a different grouping though.

[image: boxplot]

Comment: Thanks I have edited the vectors that had 16 elements. They were supposed to have 15 elements. But I want to compare by plotting three boxplots (for b,c and d) for each values of "a". That is a total of 15 boxplots.

Comment: That sounds like you want to plot a hi-lo plot, and not a boxplot. What do you wish to show with your data? The boxplot plots the median and quartiles based on the interquartile range (IQR) and summarizes spread, skewness and outliers.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is box nad whisker plot, I assumed it as an abbreviation. I wanted to show the variability of  the values of b,c and d at each "a" level. Or in other word to draw three box and whisker plot at each level of "a".

Answer (score 1):

First create a dataset in long format rather than a wide format.

```
wide <- data.frame(
  a = c(0, 100, 250, 500, 750, 0, 100, 250, 500, 750, 0, 100, 250, 500, 750),
  b = c(2.646, 3.756, 26.270, 30.997, 39.294,  2.646, 3.756, 26.270, 30.997, 39.294, 16.363, 25.950, 38.913,45.000, 47.698),
  c = c(0.0, 0.5, 0.1, 5.8, 21.9, 0.0, 0.5, 0.1, 5.8, 21.9, 9.7, 12.5, 25.1, 29.3, 31.9),
  d = c(14.7, 15.0, 13.8, 18.4, 28.2, 14.7, 15.0, 13.8, 18.4, 28.2, 23.6, 24.0, 25.7, 29.0, 33.1)
)
library(reshape2)
long <- melt(wide, id.vars = "a")
```

Then convert a into a factor you you can use it to define groups

```
long$a <- factor(long$a)
```

Finally you can plot this with ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(long, aes(x = a, y = value, colour = variable)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image: resulting figure]

Comment: Shouldn't `long <- melt(wide, id.var == "a")` read `long <- melt(wide, id.vars = "a")` with assignment to `id.vars` instead of conditional comparison with `id.var`?

Comment: Thanks Thierry. That is awesome. But when I tried the above with my real data, I got an error message like:

Comment: @noumenal,@Thierry. But when I tried the above with my real data which is similar to the above data but it is 
~1000 rows, I got an error message like:            **Error in melt_check(data, id.vars, measure.vars, variable.name, value.name) : 
  object 'id.vars' not found**

Comment: @G1124E The length is not a problem. I tried the syntax with 1500 rows. Can you paste the code that you wrote? It should be `long <- melt(wide, id.vars = "a")`. Did you read my first comment? Thierry has since updated the question. Make sure there's only one `=` and not `==` and that you are passing the keyword `id.vars` and not `id.var`.

Comment: @noumenal. Your last comment clarified the error I was having. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @noumenal@Thierry. Just for the sake of knowledge, is there another way of doing it by using only **boxplot** function with out ggplot2?